# Isolate/prevent files from being accessed by untrusted processes

Tags: filesystems, security, access-control

#### Goal

To defend against malware (or even [compromised open source libraries](https://github.com/conventional-changelog/conventional-changelog/issues/282#issuecomment-365367804)) that would [scan the filesystem and exfiltrate data](https://www.google.com/search?q=malware+scan+wallet.dat).

#### Question

- I have a certain path in my filesystem that I want only a handful of whitelisted applications to be able to access. How can I do that?

**NOTE:** I've considered alternative methods (see the edit history of the question) but am narrowing the scope to protecting a path in the filesystem.

Comment: Can't comment yet so have to post this as an answer, but SELinux may be what you're looking for; you can assign security policies to define access much more prescriptively than you could on a normal distribution.

Comment: @dsstorefile1: That would require logging in and out every time I need to access the sensitive files. I'm looking for a solution that lets one or two processes access the files (e.g. an editor I trust) in say, `/mystuff`, while all other processes can't access (or don't even see) that path.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is separate hardware and network isolation for each level of trust.

Virtual Machines are the next best thing especially when integrated like **[qubes-os](https://www.qubes-os.org/)** but may someday be susceptible to hardware bugs (rowhamer, speculative execution, firewire), or software bugs.

Containers can set a bunch of kernel security features (SELinux / AppArmor, [unshare](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unshare.1.html), [chroot](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chroot.2.html), etc) to isolate a process without the overhead of a VM.

Keep in mind there are simple solutions available to the motivated;

[image]

So it's best to just not have access to assets you don't need access to.

Personally I use a mix of the above methods; dedicated hardware for the real sensitive bits, VMs for anything not from debian/fedora, Pixel 2 Phone (only option with software updates worth mentioning) layered security (firewalls, intrusion detection systems, etc)

[prism-break](https://prism-break.org/en/) is a nice collection of software recommendations